# Could not read from the device

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to install a new version of my application on the top of the last version through Xcode.

Whenever I try to install it with the same provisional profile and details, I encountered this problem. This problem occurs after the build (while copying the files).

Has anyone faced this issue??

PS: I have attached the error screenshot:

![image: Error]

Comment: Try to reattach your device. It happens to me often because of worn cable between Mac and iPhone.

Comment: Thanks Mikheev, but I have already tried this option..

Comment: Try to replace provisioning profiles on device :)

Comment: If you have the latest iOS version on your device, make sure you also have updated your Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this!

To avoid this error, just add a user-defined build setting:

```
PREBINDING = NO
```

This would be added under the user-defined section in Build phases.

Comment: Xcode 4.3.2 lists this as an obsolete build setting and it had no affect in resolving this issue for me. Both my iPhone and iPad are unable to load compiled builds from Xcode due to this error

Comment: What does "Build phases" refer to? Is it literally what it is called in a settings file?

Answer (score 78):

What worked for me were these steps:

1. **Delete the existing app you are trying to build from iPhone/iPad**
2. Sync with iTunes
3. Kill both Xcode and iTunes completely
4. Open Xcode and Build & Run

Comment: Now, that's a great series of steps to perform while helping a colleague at the office solve this problem :))

Comment: I laughed pretty hard at this... upvote may be withdrawn if these steps don't work ;)

Comment: Booooo TheDeveloper and Zero Piraeus.... Why did you edit my steps? They were tasteful humour in reference to a Saturday Nigh Live Sketch, not profanity.! Having a sense of humour is valuable in programming and collaboration. Zero Piraeus = Zero Fun && TheDeveloper = Boooring!

Comment: 1 and 3 did it for me

Answer (score 7):

For me, just deleting the app from my device and restarting Xcode was enough. Restarting Xcode seems to be the solution to many problems these days...

Answer (score 5):

Delete the previously installed build from the device, quit Xcode, restart the device, and then install the application after cleaning all targets.

Comment: Sanjeev, i want to install the new version on the top of the old build so that my data would be retained. I don't want to delete the installed build to be removed.

Comment: unfortunately, you have to delete the previously installed build to get around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly this is a [YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/YMMV) situation. I had a very stubborn case of this, and here's what worked for me:

1. Deleted the app from the device
2. Viewed the profiles of the device in Xcode → *Organiser*
3. *I noticed there were two copies of the development profile that I was signing with installed (all profiles on the device were valid, including these two)*
4. Deleted all instances (i.e. both) of the development profile I'm signing with
5. Build and run from Xcode. The app was re-installed, along with one copy of the development profile, and it worked.

Based on this, I would try: Remove all instances of the development profile you are signing with your development profile from the device, and try running it again. I don't know if step 1 is necessary; I suspect it may not be.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, try these few steps:

- Synchronize your device in iTunes. (If you really want to save current version, make a backup **`before`** proceeding.)
- Delete the app you’re try­ing to `update` over, then restore the device from the backup.
- Synchronise again.

Finally, in Xcode, menu *Build* → *Clean* and try installing over.

I hope this helps!